# Is it possible to connect with QT to net remoting server?

Tags: .net, qt4

I have server application writed in .net. To connect with this server I'm using net remoting interface. Is it possible to connect to this server application with QT library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, .NET remoting uses an unpublished protocol. I believe it has been (at least mostly) reverse-engineered, but it would take quite a bit of work to write a Qt library to work with it.

If you want to make the API more accessible, change the .NET part to use WCF instead; WCF bindings starting with "net" should be avoided because they are also unpublished protocols. The others are defined by published standards, so it may be possible to find a Qt library to help speak a particular standardized protocol.

Alternatively, create a .NET client-side DLL to communicate with the .NET server. The DLL can then expose the needed functionality either through a C API or by acting as an inproc COM server.

Answer (score 0):

There are several differnet protocolls in .net webservices possible xml-rpc, soap, REST. If it is soap (common) then [qtsoap](http://qt.nokia.com/products/qt/addon/solutions/catalog/4/Utilities/qtsoap/) might be of help.